# Are electric forces a consequence of interaction of fields?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

An excerpt from my textbook:

> We say that the charge $Q$ produces an electric field everywhere in its surroundings. When another charge $q$ is brought at some point $P$ near it, the field there acts on it and produces a force.

".....the field there *acts on it*..." But wouldn't the charge $q$ have an electric field of its own?

So wouldn't the electric field of $Q$ "*react*" with the electric field of $q$ (and not with $q$ itself as the book states) to produce a force?

Is this correct? Can we conclude that electric forces are a consequence of interaction of two or more fields?

Please use simple terminology to explain as I'm only a novice in electrodynamics.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't two separate fields. There is a single electric field that is a function of the sizes and positions of all the charges present.

So if you start with your charges and calculate the field due to all the charges you'll get the field $\mathbf E$ that is a function of position. Note that this is a vector field so at every position in space it has both a magnitude and a direction. The force on a charge $q$ is then given by:

$$ \mathbf F = q \mathbf E $$

where $\mathbf E$ is the field at the position of the charge. Note that the force is also a vector so just like the field it has a magnitude and a direction.

Comment: ty for the answer, but I'm totally confused. Are you saying that only one electric field can exist, the two charges don't have separate fields?? Is there any book that I can refer to, to understand these concepts better?

Comment: Yes there are lots of books, but it's hard to find good ones. If you read Deep Down Things by Bruce Schumm and stick with it, you will get a good idea of how fields are used to explain forces. Or Sean Carroll, The Particle at the end of the Universe. Both, together with large amounts of aspirin, should help you.

Comment: As @John said, the only meaningful quantity is the electric field at a point due to a system of charges. Now, since they're vectors, the this field can be broken into "contributions" from (say) two different charges, and since the quantities are linear, we could say that the field at any point is the sum of two contributions: first by imagining the charge $q$ alone in the universe, then by imagining the charge $Q$ alone. These two contributions are what we call the electric field of $q$ and $Q$, but ideally should be thought of as "the field if $q$/$Q$ was the alone in the universe."